# How to retrieve entities from Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, nosql

I have some problems with Cloud Datastore in Google App Engine.

I have 2 Models in the database which are:

```
class Product(ndb.Model):
    name = StringProperty(required=True)
    category = KeyProperty(kind=Category)
    description = TextProperty(required=True)
    price = IntegerProperty(required=True)
```

And

```
class Category(ndb.Model):
    name=StringProperty(required=True)
```

So how can i get all the datas from Product Class that belong to a certain Category?

In Relational SQL i used:

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE category = 'CertainName';
```

Thank you!

Comment: That's not really true ... In relational SQL you would need to join the Product table with the Category table before you could do your selection.  Unfortunately for you, the datastore doesn't support joins in queries.  You'd need to either fetch everything and do the join yourself in code or fetch all the categories and then query for products by the category keys (likely _really_ inefficient) or come up with a different data model...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should perform what your sql query is doing:

```
query = Product.query(Product.category == "CertainName") # Note the "=="
```

Edit:

I just realized you need to filter by key(thank you @mgilson). The query changes a little. Basically you just need to first get your category_entity and then apply the filter like this:

```
query = Product.query(Product.category == category_entity.key)
```

where, for example, you could fetch a category_entity like shown below:

```
category_entity = Category.query(Category.name == "SomeCat").fetch()
```

Refer to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/ndb/queries/snippets.py for more info (look at query_purchases_for_customer_via_key)

Comment: But `Product.category` is a _key_ field -- Not a string field so this query will not work.  Unfortunately, OP is trying to join across "tables" which never really works well in most NoSQL environments as far as I'm aware (though I'm not an expert by any means ...)

Comment: @mgilson it's possible to filter by key. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard/ndb/queries/snippets.py has some examples

Comment: Right -- I'm not disputing whether that is possible either -- But what it looks to me is that OP wants something like:  `Product.query(product.category.IN(Category.query(Category.name == 'CategoryName').fetch(keys_only=True)))`.  This _might_ work if the category query returns few enough results, but it's will be inefficient at best ... My point is that OP is trying to query the `Product` table by something that is in the `Category` table which is not supported well by NoSQL databases or at least the google datastore.

Comment: Hmm, from what I understood(looking at the query) it looks like this is a filter by a property in the Table. So there is no need to join in this case. Well anyway, I'll let the OP get back on what he wants.

Comment: Many thanks for your helps. But I'm very new to Datastore so what does the "category_entity.key" means? and how can i create that one?

Comment: category_entity is the category object you are interested in filtering by. Example: category_entity = Category.query(Category.name=="SomeCat").fetch() and you can access the key by calling category_entity.key

Answer (score 0):

You could generate your own key in class Category based on the 'name' field and use it:

1) when you generate a new Category entity

2) when you need to query Product against a specific category.

So after Category entities have a key you can generate at any time, you could say:

category_key = Category.create_key(name='CertainName')

query = Product.query(Product.category == category_key)

Comment: Thanks for your help. But i could not use the create_key() function.

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'Owner' has no attribute 'create_key' this is error of that case

Comment: You need to implement create_key() on you own inside Category class definition and return something like ndb.Key(Category, name).

Comment: You can get more insight in the docs (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/creating-entity-keys)